# itext7 - change background color of checked radio button

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using itext7 plugin in Unity (C#) to compile an interactive PDF.
My customer want to highlight the fields that are compiled, and I have not problems to do this with text fields using:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
Color bg = new DeviceRgb(135, 215, 238);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);
Dictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("nameofthefield", out toSet);

toSet.SetValue("texttowrite");
toSet.SetBackgroundColor(bg);
```

But with radio buttons if I do the same thing I color all the radio buttons, not only the checked one. I cannot find a way to retrieve the single value and add the background color to it. Anyone can help me??

I

Answer (score 0):

Use `pdfForm.GetFormFields()` to get all your formfields. You see that (depending on the editor) the specific fields are usually called

radOption.1
radOption.2
radOption.3
...

You must set the background color of the specific input.

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on the editor"? The OP asked in the context [tag:itext7], a specific PDF library. Also multiple options for the same PDF form value are modelled using a single field with multiple widgets (unless you try some JavaScript magic), so `pdfForm.GetFormFields()`  will have only a single entry for all those options. (Other software may handle that differently.)

Comment: It totally depends in the editor that created the PDF document. For me it seams like the author just wants to fill an existing formular. In general radio buttons have a "pseudo form field" for the group and a form field for every option. Setting values on the pseudo field (e.g.) background sets it for all the related options.